# How to automatically update AUR packages in Octopi

Tags: manjaro

Similar to [this old thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ManjaroLinux/comments/ao1ml3/how_to_update_aur_package_using_octopi/?ref=share&ref_source=link), when Octopi syncs, it only pulls updates from the official repos and does not update the latest AUR packages. Do I have to do this manually or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in `Tools > Options` to set this, but its phrasing is confusing and it is off by default: "Search for outdated AUR packages"
[image: Options]

Then your next sync will look for AUR updates too:

[image: 16 packages to update]